# How to make a form field required only if another field is filled and vice versa in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I made the following form in Django.

```
class SearchTimeSlotsForm(forms.Form):
    available_from = forms.TimeField(widget=TimeInput())
    available_till = forms.TimeField(widget=TimeInput())
```

In the above form the user can either fill both the fields or may not fill any field but he cannot fill only one field.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to implement it is by validating the form once it's posted. Another option is to write some JS that validates the second field in the browser only if the first field is filled out, but that is more complicated and probably unnecessary.

By default, all fields are marked as required unless you specify otherwise. You can validate each field by defining a `clean_<field_name>` value. If you have more complex validation logic that includes multiple fields, you should override the `clean` method.

```py
class SearchTimeSlotsForm(forms.Form):
    # Both fields are individually optional
    available_from = forms.TimeField(widget=TimeInput(), required=False)
    available_till = forms.TimeField(widget=TimeInput(), required=False)

    # Override clean cause validation logic includes both fields
    def clean(self):
        available_from = self.cleaned_data.get('available_from')
        available_till = self.cleaned_data.get('available_till')

        if not available_from and not available_till:
            # Here we're raising a ValidationError that refers to a specific
            # field so the error is better pointed out to the user.
            raise ValidationError({
                'available_till': ValidationError(
                    'If you fill in available_from field, you also need to '
                    'fill out available_till.', 
                    code='required'
                )
            })

        return self.cleaned_data
```